# Show zoomed view of bitmap on canvas at fix position similiar to magnifying glass

Tags: android, image, canvas, zooming, magnify

Hie,
I have a canvas with bitmap image on it.Now i want to zoom touched portion and display it at fix position on canvas.Just how the magnifying glass works.Till now i am able to display zoomed view of touched portion on bitmap but the problem is it keeps on moving with the finger touch and when i try to fix its position, it produces inaccurate results.Badly stucked please do help!

[image: Bitmap on canvas when not touched]

[image: Magnifying glass showing zoomed view hovering with bitmap touch]

Comment: Did u found any solution?? @Iram

Comment: Did u found any solution?? @Iram

Comment: Did u found any solution?? @Iram